# Give permission to non-admin user to view and edit list of orders

Tags: 7, commerce

I am trying to create a role and assign it to a user who can view the admin orders list page and also edit the orders.

After adding all the permissions under the order sections in the permissions page, I was not able to access the list of the orders but was able to see the orders separately and edit them using the order number.

`admin/commerce/orders` page was accessible but the list was not showing.

Why is this happening? Is there any way fix this?
From the screenshot, you can see that I have given all the required permissions with respect to orders.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After comparing the query being executed for the admin user and the non-admin user I found that `1=0` is being added to the `commerce_orders` view's query.

Further checking out the code, it seems that in the `commerce.module` file, the code expects either shipping or billing permission being granted to the user.

After adding one of them, the list was visible. I don't know why it's like this, List of orders must not expect that permission right?

**TLDR;** Adding the billing/shipping permission fixed the issue.